# How can I replace records into another dataset?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to copy records of a few employees from one company into another larger one. If a primary key duplicate conflict occurs, the record has to be replaced. For Delphi DataSet there are commands "Insert", "Append", "Edit", and "Delete", but is there an easy way to "Replace" the record between the same tables, without knowing the full table structure or primary keys? There are like 30+ fields and they may be changed in the future.

In MySQL it would be `REPLACE INTO table2 (SELECT * FROM table1)` but I wanted to change a few fields in the target table, like employee's ID and department codes.

Comment: Normally I would recommend the FireDAC BatchMove component with Mode set to dmAppendUpdate, but as you seem stuck with Delphi 7 this is probably not helpful.

Comment: @UweRaabe I already came up with a solution, but BatchMove seems interesting because I am using MyDAC and there is a CRBatchMove component. Can you show me an example of how to use BatchMove?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to replace/overwrite dataset records in Delphi. But using MySQL I can select the source data into a temp table, modify the temp table data, and place it into target table.